# ns-3 wlan grid TCP not working while UDP is

Tags: tcp, wifi, network-protocols, ns-3

I am trying to set up a Multihop AdHoc 802.11g Network in ns-3.
To get started I used the example 'wifi-simple-adhoc-grid.cc'.

The example uses UDP, but I want to use TCP. Therefore I switched

```
TypeId tid = ns3::UdpSocketFactory::GetTypeId();
Ptr<Socket> recvSink = Socket::CreateSocket (c.Get (sinkNode), tid);
InetSocketAddress local = InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), 80);
recvSink->Bind (local);
recvSink->SetRecvCallback (MakeCallback (&ReceivePacket));
```

to

```
TypeId tid = ns3::TcpSocketFactory::GetTypeId();
Ptr<Socket> recvSink = Socket::CreateSocket (c.Get (sinkNode), tid);
InetSocketAddress local = InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), 80);
recvSink->Bind (local);
recvSink->SetRecvCallback (MakeCallback (&ReceivePacket));

Ptr<Socket> source = Socket::CreateSocket (c.Get (sourceNode), tid);
InetSocketAddress remote = InetSocketAddress (i.GetAddress (sinkNode, 0), 80);
```

Sending Packets is no Problem, but ReceivePacket is never called, which means, that socket Sink receives no packets.

The whole code: https://gist.github.com/3023757

[Routes output](https://gist.github.com/3023751) by:

```
Ptr<OutputStreamWrapper> routingStream = Create<OutputStreamWrapper> 
("wifi-multihop.routes", std::ios::out)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue - the callback I give SetRecvCallback is never called, even though data is sent to the node.

Comment: Did the solution provided below work? I took your code from the link you provided and ran it with the suggestion given in answer, the TCP packets atill are not shown received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call SetRevCallback function your  SetAcceptCallback function.

Explicitly,

```
recvSink->SetAcceptCallback (MakeNullCallback<bool, Ptr<Socket>,const Address &> (),MakeCallback(&accept));
```

In the accept function

```
void accept(Ptr<Socket> socket,const ns3::Address& from)
{

    std::cout<<"Connection accepted"<< std::endl;
    socket->SetRecvCallback (MakeCallback (&ReceivePacket));

}
```

Comment: Hi @user75176, thanks for your contribution please format your answer properly. You might find this [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) useful.