# Unable to Call Tcp Socket Received Callback Function on NS3

Tags: c++, ns-3

I am new with NS3. I am trying to create a custom application and currently have a difficulty on calling a Socket callback function using socket->SetRecvCallback. This problem occur while I use TcpSocketFactory, another socket such as UDP does not produce this issue.

**On main**

```
Ptr<Socket> ns3TcpSocket = Socket::CreateSocket(nodes.Get(0), TcpSocketFactory::GetTypeId());
```

**Custom Tcp Application Class**

```
this->socket->SetRecvCallback(MakeCallback(&CustomTcpApplication::RecvCallback, this));
this->socket->SetSendCallback(MakeCallback(&CustomTcpApplication::WriteUntilBufferFull, this));
```

**My callback function**

```
void CustomTcpApplication::RecvCallback(Ptr<Socket> socket)
{
    std::cout << "On Receive Callback Function" << std::endl;
}


void CustomTcpApplication::WriteUntilBufferFull(Ptr<Socket> localSocket, uint32_t txSpace)
{
    std::cout << "On Send Callback Function" << std::endl;
}
```

Also. I read from this answer to implements SetAcceptCallback, [ns-3 wlan grid TCP not working while UDP is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274459/ns-3-wlan-grid-tcp-not-working-while-udp-is)

```
this->socket->SetAcceptCallback(MakeNullCallback<bool, Ptr<Socket>, const Address &>(), MakeCallback(&CustomTcpApplication::Accept, this));
```

**Callback Function**

```
void CustomTcpApplication::Accept(Ptr<Socket> socket, const ns3::Address& from)
{
    std::cout << "Connection accepted" << std::endl;
    socket->SetRecvCallback(MakeCallback(&CustomTcpApplication::MainRecvCallback, this));
}
```

However, I still cannot log it on the function. Did I missing any step?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today. After tracing codes for hours, I found that there is no native support for TCP data receiving callback.

The tcp-socket-base.cc forks a new TcpSocketBase object for the following data transmission in TcpSocketBase::ProcessListen().**The copy constructor of TcpSocketBase resets new socket's callback functions including m_receivedData**. That's why data receiving callback doesn't work for TCP.

A simple workaround is to reserve the callback variable from original TcpSocketBase and make m_receivedDataTCP public in src/network/model/socket.h.

```
TcpSocketBase::TcpSocketBase (const TcpSocketBase& sock)
{
   ...
   m_receivedDataTCP = sock.m_receivedDataTCP;
}
```